# docker no conecta con mongo local

Tags: docker

Tengo un contenedor node básico

```
ROM node:boron
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

pero al lanzarlo trata de conectar con `mongodb://localhost:27017/my-bd` que es un mongo local en mi mac...

Esto genera el siguiente error:

```
 Unable to ensure uniqueness for usernames:  MongoNetworkError: 
failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect 
[MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Estoy probando a exponer el 27017 pero da el mismo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba a desplegar tu contenedor con la opción --netwok host, o bien, en vez de decirle que se conecte a localhost:27017, que se conecte a la ip de tu host.

Esto se debe a que cuando despliegas tu contenedor va a tener su ip propia a no ser que le digas lo contrario.

La maquina donde tienes el docker engine(y mongo) tendrá una ip X, mientras que el contenedor tendrá una ip Y. El contenedor cuando le dices que se conecte a localhost buscara en la ip Y, cuando debería buscar en X.

Mi consejo es que modifiques el conector para que se conecte a una dirección llamada mongohost (por ejemplo) y cuando hagas run del container lo hagas de la siguiente forma:

```
run -d --add-host mongohost:"IP-Host-de-mongo" nombre-imagen
```

Con esto podrás tener el servidor de mongo en cualquier host que le especifiques al contenedor cuando lo pongas en marcha.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.